# Dropdown choice not retained on page submit/reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-chosen

So I've got a Checkout page collecting a shipping and billing address. The country and state options use dropdown boxes from [Chosen by Harvest](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to give a different list of states for each country. However, on submit, the page reloads with an updated shipping cost, and in doing so, the selected state reverts back to the first choice (i.e. Alaska). The country option is retained, but something in the way the state options are generated is keeping the state option from being retained.

Here's the relevant javascript:

```
var GBSStates;
(function(j){
/*!
 * Simple JavaScript Inheritance
 * By John Resig http://ejohn.org/
 * MIT Licensed.
 *
 * Extended by Jonathon Byrd to include function hooks
 * https://gist.github.com/Jonathonbyrd/724083
 *
 * Don't forget your Shims!
 * https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master
 */
(function(){var a=false,b=/xyz/.test(function(){xyz})?/\b_super\b/:/.*/;function c(h){var f=h,e={before:[],after:[]};function g(){var j=[].slice.call(arguments,0),k=0,l;for(k=0;!!e.before[k];k+=1){l=e.before[k];l.apply(this,j)}var m=f.apply(this,arguments);for(k=0;!!e.after[k];k++){l=e.after[k];l.apply(this,j)}return m}g.bind=function(i){if(typeof this!=="function"){throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable")}var m=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1),l=this,j=function(){},k=function(){return l.apply(this instanceof j&&i?this:i,m.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)))};j.prototype=this.prototype;k.prototype=new j();return k};g.addHook=function(j,i){if(e[j] instanceof Array){e[j].push(i)}else{throw (function(){var k=new Error("Invalid hook type");k.expected=Object.keys(e);k.got=j;return k}())}};return g}function d(f,e){if(typeof jQuery=="undefined"){return f}return jQuery.extend(true,e,f)}this._Class=function(){};_Class.extend=function(i){var g=this.prototype;a=true;var f=new this();a=false;for(var e in i){f[e]=typeof i[e]=="function"&&typeof g[e]=="function"&&b.test(i[e])?(function(j,k){return function(){var m=this._super;this._super=g[j];var l=k.apply(this,arguments);this._super=m;return l}})(e,i[e]):(typeof i[e]=="function"?c(i[e]):(typeof i[e]=="object"&&typeof g[e]=="object"?d(i[e],g[e]):i[e]))}function h(){if(!a&&this.init){this.init.apply(this,arguments)}}h.prototype=f;h.constructor=h;h.extend=c(arguments.callee);return h}})();Class=_Class.extend({defaults:{container:null},data:{},init:function(a){this.setOptions(a)},setOptions:function(c){var b=new Object();for(var a in this.defaults){b[a]=this.defaults[a]}for(var a in c){b[a]=c[a]}this.data=b;return this},set:function(b,a){this.data[b]=a},get:function(a,b){return typeof this.data[a]!="undefined"?this.data[a]:b},element:function(){return this.get("container")},rawElement:function(){return this.element().context},uid:function(){return this._uid().replace(/[/,'').replace(/]/,"").replace(/:/,"")},_uid:function(){if(this.element().attr("id")){return this.element().attr("id")}if(this.element().attr("name")){return this.element().attr("name")}var a="";if(this.element().context.form.id){a=this.element().context.form.id}if(!a&&this.element().context.form.name){a=this.element().context.form.name}return a+this.element().index()}});
GBSStates = Class.extend({
    defaults : {
            container : null,
            stateselect : '#gb_billing_zone',
            stateselectparent : null,
            hiddenstate : '#gb_billing_zone_text',
            hiddenstateparent : null,
            states : [],
            chosen : {
                allow_single_deselect: true,
                no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
                width: '300px'
            }
    },

    // Initializing
    init: function(o)
    {
            this.setOptions(o);
            this.set('stateselect', j(this.get('stateselect')));
            this.set('stateselectparent', this.get('stateselect')
                    .closest('tr'));

            this.set('hiddenstate', j(this.get('hiddenstate')));
            this.set('hiddenstateparent', this.get('hiddenstate')
                    .closest('tr'));

            this.storeOriginal();
            this.addListeners();
            this.recreate();
    },

        // store the original select box
        storeOriginal: function()
        {
            var optgroups = {};
            j(this.get('stateselect')).find('optgroup').each(function(k,v){
                var options = {};
                j(this).find('option').each(function(k,v){
                    options[j(v).val()] = j(v).text();
                });
                optgroups[j(v).attr('label')] = options;
            });
            this.set('states', optgroups);

            // delete the original
            j(this.get('stateselect')).find('optgroup').remove();
        },

        // create the chosen select boxes and set the listeners
    addListeners: function()
    {
            this.get('stateselect').chosen(this.get('chosen'))
                    .change(this.update.bind(this));

            this.element().chosen(this.get('chosen'))
                    .change(this.recreate.bind(this));
    },


        update: function(e)
        {
            var chosenstate = j(e.currentTarget);
            this.get('hiddenstate').val( chosenstate.val() );
        },

        // recreate the state select boxes
        recreate: function()
        {
            var country = this.element().val();
            var states = this.get('states')[country];
            var stateselect = this.get('stateselect');

            if (states) { // enable chosen select box
                this.get('hiddenstate').val('');
                this.get('hiddenstateparent').hide();
                this.get('stateselectparent').show();

                stateselect.find('option').remove();
                j.each(states, function( k, v ){
                    // k is the key from opts, ex : value_1
                    // v is the value attributet to k, ex : value #1
                    j('<option />', { 
                        text : v,
                        value : k
                    }).appendTo( stateselect );
                });

                //stateselect.trigger("chosen:updated");
                stateselect.data("chosen").destroy().chosen(this.get('chosen'));

            } else { // enable text field
                this.get('hiddenstateparent').show();
                this.get('stateselectparent').hide();
            }
        }
});
j.fn.GBSStates = function(o){
    // initializing
    var args = arguments;
    var o = o || {'container':''};
    return this.each(function(){
        // load the saved object
        var api = j.data(this, 'GBSStates');
        // create and save the object if it does not exist
        if (!api) {
            o.container = j(this);
            api = new GBSStates(o);
            j.data(this, 'GBSStates', api);
        }
                if (typeof api[o] == 'function') {
                        if (args[0] == o) delete args[0];
                        api[o].bind(api);
                        var parameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1);
                        return api[o].apply(api,parameters);
               }
        return api;
    });
};
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#gb_billing_country').GBSStates({
        stateselect : '#gb_billing_zone'
    });
    jQuery('#gb_shipping_country').GBSStates({
        stateselect : '#gb_shipping_zone',
        hiddenstate : '#gb_shipping_zone_text',
    });
});
```

Unfortunately I didn't write this, and I am fairly unfamiliar with JavaScript, so any help would be extremely appreciated!

Oh and one more thing I found when trying to figure out what's going on:
When viewing the source of the page after submitting and updating the tax, the html shows the correct state as being "selected", even though Alaska is what's being displayed:

`<option value="WA"  selected='selected'>Washington</option>`

EDIT: Here's some relevant PHP code that uses the JavaScript above:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Function is activated by the gb_valid_process_payment_page filter
 * 
 * @param type $verify
 * @param Group_Buying_Checkouts $checkout
 * @return type
 */
function gbsstates_capture_state( $verify, Group_Buying_Checkouts $checkout )
{
    // set billing state
    $zone = isset($_POST['gb_billing_zone_text']) &&$_POST['gb_billing_zone_text']
            ?$_POST['gb_billing_zone_text']
            :(isset($_POST['gb_billing_zone'])?$_POST['gb_billing_zone']
            :$checkout->cache['billing']['zone']);
    $checkout->cache['billing']['zone'] = $zone;

    // set shipping state
    $zone = isset($_POST['gb_shipping_zone_text']) &&$_POST['gb_shipping_zone_text']
            ?$_POST['gb_shipping_zone_text']
            :(isset($_POST['gb_shipping_zone'])?$_POST['gb_shipping_zone']
            :$checkout->cache['shipping']['zone']);
    $checkout->cache['shipping']['zone'] = $zone;

    // pass through the verify boolean
    return $verify; 
}

/**
 * fired on gb_checkout_fields_billing action. it adds an additional hidden
 * field to the array
 * 
 * @param type $fields
 * @return array()
 */
function gbsstates_add_textfield_zone( $fields = array() )
{
    $fields['zone_text'] = array(
            'weight' => 13,
            'label' => __( 'State' ),
            'type' => 'text'
    );

    return $fields;
}

/**
 * Function upgrades the fields array
 * 
 * @param type $states
 */
function gbsstates_set_checkout_fields_array( $states = array(), $args = array() ){
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'gbsstates',
        plugins_url( '/js/states.js' , __DIR__ ),
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'chosen',
        plugins_url( '/js/chosen.jquery.min.js' , __DIR__ ),
        array( 'gbsstates' )
    );
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'chosen',
        plugins_url( '/css/chosen.css' , __DIR__ )
    );

    $states = gbsstates_statearray_minimal();
    if ( isset( $args['include_option_none'] ) && $args['include_option_none'] ) {
        $states = array( '' => array('' => $args['include_option_none'] ))
                            + $states;
    }
    return $states;
}

/**
 * This function returns an array of states
 * 
 * @return array()
 */
function gbsstates_statearray_minimal() { 
    return array(
        'US'                 => array(
            'AK'             => 'Alaska',
            'AL'             => 'Alabama',
            'AR'             => 'Arkansas',
            'AZ'             => 'Arizona',
            'CA'             => 'California',
            'CO'             => 'Colorado',
            'CT'             => 'Connecticut',
            'DC'             => 'District Of Columbia',
            'DE'             => 'Delaware',
            'FL'             => 'Florida',
            'GA'             => 'Georgia',
            'HI'             => 'Hawaii',
            'IA'             => 'Iowa',
            'ID'             => 'Idaho',
            'IL'             => 'Illinois',
            'IN'             => 'Indiana',
            'KS'             => 'Kansas',
            'KY'             => 'Kentucky',
            'LA'             => 'Louisiana',
            'MA'             => 'Massachusetts',
            'MD'             => 'Maryland',
            'ME'             => 'Maine',
            'MI'             => 'Michigan',
            'MN'             => 'Minnesota',
            'MO'             => 'Missouri',
            'MS'             => 'Mississippi',
            'MT'             => 'Montana',
            'NC'             => 'North Carolina',
            'ND'             => 'North Dakota',
            'NE'             => 'Nebraska',
            'NH'             => 'New Hampshire',
            'NJ'             => 'New Jersey',
            'NM'             => 'New Mexico',
            'NV'             => 'Nevada',
            'NY'             => 'New York',
            'OH'             => 'Ohio',
            'OK'             => 'Oklahoma',
            'OR'             => 'Oregon',
            'PA'             => 'Pennsylvania',
            'RI'             => 'Rhode Island',
            'SC'             => 'South Carolina',
            'SD'             => 'South Dakota',
            'TN'             => 'Tennessee',
            'TX'             => 'Texas',
            'UT'             => 'Utah',
            'VA'             => 'Virginia',
            'VT'             => 'Vermont',
            'WA'             => 'Washington',
            'WI'             => 'Wisconsin',
            'WV'             => 'West Virginia',
            'WY'             => 'Wyoming'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Does this exact code control the country select that is working? If not, it might be good to include that code. Or perhaps you could go through the two and point out any differences. FYI, that seems like a lot of overhead for a select box.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the country dropdown is not using any separate code from the state dropdown. I've added some relevant PHP code above.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload a page it's normal that all forms clear. There are two solutions for this.

1. Save the input
   You could use localstorage to save the input value before the page reloads than checking if the localstorage variable exists and if so changing the default state to that one.
2. Don't reload
   You could also (if your calculations are done in JS) recalculate the price live when the value changes. Then you could use jquery for example to change the price shown. This is by far the easiest and most efficient way. It's also giving a better user experience because there's no delay.

Comment: Recalculating the price live is a great idea, I'll see if it can be done. It seems, however, that the country dropdown is currently functioning as I was hoping the state dropdown would, so it's saving the input in either the javascript or somewhere in the PHP.